# Flask + mod_wsgi + HEAD headers processing: unable to get bucket brigade for request

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have the following stack: Flask (python 2.7) + Apache2 with mod_wsgi.

I have this simple route function:

```
@app.route("/upload/<file_name>/", methods=['POST', 'HEAD'])
def upload(file_name):       
    if request.method == 'HEAD':    
        file_size = int(request.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        file_path = os.path.join(storage_path, file_name)

        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            return general_response(404)    
        else:
            file_size_on_disk = Utils.get_size_of_file(file_path)
            if file_size_on_disk < file_size:
                print "1"
                return general_response(201)
            elif file_size_on_disk == file_size:
                print "2"
                return general_response(200)    
            else:
                print "4"
                return general_response(500)

    # some code
```

If I send HEAD request **without** any headers - I receive proper response for my request in REST client, but if I send HEAD request with 'Content-Length' header with some value - I see in log:

```
2
```

And this is right behavior because that part of code should executed in that case, but **no response** from server after printing "2"...

If I abort connection in my REST client - I see the following line in log:

`(70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: mod_wsgi (pid=11509): Unable to get bucket brigade for request`

This is my apache2 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin Admin
    ServerName site.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/app.wsgi

    WSGIDaemonProcess app_name user=worker group=worker processes=1 threads=5

    DocumentRoot /path/to/src/dir
    <Directory /path/to/src/dir>
        LimitRequestBody 4147483647
        WSGIProcessGroup app_name
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I really cannot realize why receiving this header with a value breaks wsgi logic at all.

Any help/advice will be appreciated!

Comment: You should even see a ``HEAD`` request. This is because mod_wsgi will map ``HEAD`` to ``GET`` usually because most WSGI applications don't handle ``HEAD`` properly and return results that do not match what would be returned by ``GET``. There is a directive one can set to have original ``HEAD`` passed through, but you don't show it as being set. What code do you have for handling of ``GET``? Have you added debugging to verify you are being passed a ``HEAD`` request? What mod_wsgi version are you using?

Comment: 1) I don't handle GET requests in this route function. Or what do you mean?
2) No I didn't. Do you mean smth like this https://gist.github.com/b4oshany/350305ef729fcc70fda1?
3) libapache2-mod-wsgi, 4.3.0-1.1build1, amd64
Can you advise how to properly handle such action - when I need to respond to HEAD request with specified header?

Comment: Also, can you please explain what this phrase means "bucket brigade"?

Comment: I meant: You should NOT even see a ``HEAD`` request. You are on quite old mod_wsgi version. From 4.3.0 onwards you could disable the mapping of ``HEAD`` to ``GET`` by setting the directive ``WSGIMapHEADToGET Off`` in the Apache configuration. Not so concerned about bucket brigade error at this point as Apache can sometimes spit out strange messages related to the bucket brigade when connections are broken, especially if using secure connections.